# Develop a custom floating sidebar in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to develop a floating sidebar in Wordpress? 
for example adding an HTML code such as subscription button.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use a widget area and float that since it's easier and better to float widget area than to float the whole sidebar.

Try **[Q2W3 Fixed Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/q2w3-fixed-widget/)** plugin which should help you.

If you have any problems, follow this nice [tutorial from WPBeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-create-a-sticky-floating-sidebar-widget-in-wordpress/).

and it's always best to post link to your website or theme to give a better idea of the problem :)

Good luck!

Comment: I've tried to use the  Q2W3 Fixed Widget plugin before but it seems i have a problem when i use the right sidebar template in my theme.

Comment: You should post a link to your website/webpage explaining your problem so that i can understand the problem better.

Comment: this is a test page I'm working on http://changezone.com/test-widgets/ , see the right sidebar i need to place these icons in a floating sidebar similar to the one I'm sing here http://changezone.com/

Comment: @AhmadFouta, did you check the sign in Widgets page on the respective widget where it says "Fixed Widget"? you might be missing that since it's the main thing which controls it.